# vbScript AppActivate activates random apps

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

I am trying to write a vb-script to do the following

1. Launch Chrome
2. Navigate to a specified website
3. Loop and keep refreshing that specific tab

I am able to get #1 and #2 to work, using the following code. The refresh works as well. The only issue is that the refresh happens to the windows which are active. The AppActivate part - which is supposed to shift focus to a given window is not working. Code here.

```
Dim iURL
Dim objShell

iURL = "SampleURL"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1

Do While True

   Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   WSHShell.AppActivate "Remote Access Asia - Google Chrome"

   WSHShell.SendKeys "{F5}"

   WScript.Sleep 30000    ' 30 seconds

Loop
```

The window title I am using was determined by using the tasklist command (tasklist /v /FO:CSV). I have tried using various versions (substrings) of the title shown. I have used chrome.exe as well, but nothing helps. The refresh is not limited to tabs of Chrome - it happens with other apps e.g. notepad as well.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for a Chrome window I already had open. The issue may be with `ShellExecute`. I had success using `Run` and ensuring the site opened in its own window using the `--new-window` parameter. It's also unnecessary to have the `CreateObject` inside the `While` loop. Try it like this:

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
URL = "SampleURL"

oWSH.Run "chrome.exe --new-window " & URL

Do While True
 oWSH.AppActivate "Remote Access Asia - Google Chrome"
 oWSH.SendKeys "{F5}"
 WScript.Sleep 30000  '30 seconds
Loop
```